# How to use react semantic ui Dropdown to show number of pages and selected page on right side?

Tags: semantic-ui-react

I am new to react. I am following https://www.truecodex.com/course/react-js this example but in this example, it shows all the customers. I want to add a dropdown with no. of pages and on-page selection changes the values in the table.

I think, I should take one more customer{} and add 1-4customer 2-next4customer and then on dropdown selection on change change the table values

[image: I am trying to create something like this]

Here is my Customer view class where I am fetching all customers.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Table,Icon, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';

export default class CustomerView extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        error: null,
        deleteTitle: "customer",
        isLoaded: false,
        formClose: false,
        singleCustomer: [],
        users: []
    }
}

//fetch data 
componentDidMount() {

    const customerApi = 'https://localhost:44387/api/Customers';

    const myHeader = new Headers();
    myHeader.append('Content-type', 'application/json');
    myHeader.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    myHeader.append('Origin', 'https://localhost:44387');

    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        myHeader
    };

    fetch(customerApi, options)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {
                this.setState({
                    users: result,
                    isLoaded: true
                });
            },
            (error) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: false,
                    error
                });
            }
        )
}

//Delete Customer

onDeleteCustomer = customerId => {

    const { users } = this.state;
    this.setState({
        users: users.filter(customer => customer.customerId !== customerId)
    });

    const customerApi = 'https://localhost:44387/api/Customers/' + customerId;

    const myHeader = new Headers({
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    });

    fetch(customerApi, {
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: myHeader

    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {
                this.setState({

                })
            }, (error) => {
                this.setState({ error });
            }
        )
}

render() {
    const { users } = this.state;

    return (
        <div>

            <Button color='blue' onClick={() => this.props.onCreate()}>New Customer</Button>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <Table celled textAlign='center'>
                <Table.Header>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>ID</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Name</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Address</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Action</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Action</Table.HeaderCell>
                    </Table.Row>
                </Table.Header>

                <Table.Body >
                    {
                        users.map(user => (
                            <Table.Row key={user.customerId}>

                                <Table.Cell>{user.customerId}</Table.Cell>
                                <Table.Cell>{user.name}</Table.Cell>
                                <Table.Cell>{user.address}</Table.Cell>

                                <Table.Cell>
                                    <Button color='yellow' icon labelPosition='right' 
                                        onClick={() => this.props.onEditCustomer(user.customerId)}>
                                            <Icon name='edit outline'/>
                                            Edit</Button>
                                </Table.Cell>

                                <Table.Cell>
                                    <Button color='red' icon labelPosition='right' 
                                        onClick={() => this.props.onDeleteClick(user.customerId)}>
                                            <Icon name='trash alternate'/>
                                            Delete</Button>
                                </Table.Cell>

                            </Table.Row>
                        ))
                    }
                </Table.Body>

                <Table.Footer>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <Table.HeaderCell colSpan='5'>
                            No of Pages
                    </Table.HeaderCell>
                    </Table.Row>
                </Table.Footer>
            </Table>

        </div>
    )
}

}
```